# All informations (including images) in a row strikethrough using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to strikethrough all informations in one row using css...here is my input

[image]

Currently I used this css to change the color - let say it become disabled.

```
table.answer tr.disabled td{
    color:#eee !important;
    background:#f9f9f9 !important;
    border-color:#ccc !important;
}
table.answer tr.disabled td.last{
    color:#333 !important;
    background:#f9f9f9 !important;
    border-color:#ccc !important;
}
```

I used jquery - to add the `disabled` class to the `tr` on the table.

Let say this function run when user click `ignore` button.

```
$('#row_'+id).addClass('disabled');
```

My requirement is if user click the button image labeled **ignore**...then all the information on that row become as below:

[image]

Before this I just only change the color...but it just work for the fonts only but not the image...

[image]

Comment: Please provide some HTML and CSS, thank you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for posting some code, however, to answer properly it would be good if you could include full HTML, CSS and JavaScript that allows us to reproduce your issue. At the moment we will need to fill in some gaps in your code before we can address your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a style to the `:before` or `:after` on the `disabled` class for the `tr`. However I found that this adds a small border to the beginning or end of the row.

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.disabled:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 18px;
  content: '';
  width: 95%;
  height: 3px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr class="disabled">
    <td>C</td>
    <td style="width: 50%;">Content</td>
    <td>Ignore</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'll be adding a jQuery alternative here shortly.

### Edit

Here is a jQuery solution that removes the weird border at the end of the row. I used a container `<div>` to apply the strikeout to rather than the actual table itself.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/press/254efocp/1/)**

```js
$('.disabled').each(function() {

  var me = $(this),
    s = $('.strikeout'),
    d = $('<div></div>'),
    p = me.position(),
    h = me.height();

  d.addClass('disabled-div').css('top', 8 + p.top);
  s.append(d);

});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.strikeout {
  position: relative;
}
.disabled1:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  content: '';
  width: 95%;
  height: 3px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.disabled-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 18px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 3px;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="strikeout">
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr class="disabled">
      <td>123</td>
      <td style="width: 50%;">321</td>
      <td>Ignore</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="disabled">
      <td>123</td>
      <td style="width: 50%;">321</td>
      <td>Ignore</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td style="width: 50%;">321</td>
      <td>Ignore</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```